# Spawning down the middle of the screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, spawning

Is there a way to spawn an SKSpriteNode    continuously down the middle of the screen. For example I have a circle that I want to spawn in the middle of the x axis and then for that node to spawn all the way down the screen?

These circles are different colours so when they spawn is there a way to randomly change the the colour of the circles when they are spawned?

I understand I can spawn them individually but is there a better way? ( I am using SpriteKit on swift)

Comment: What do you mean 'spawn in the middle of the x axis and fhen for the node to spawn all the way down the screen'?

Comment: Sorry, I may have meant the y axis as I would these circle nodes to spawn down the middle of the screen in a straight line down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some basics bruh.
Learn about For loops, arrays and arc4random.

```
        var circleDiameter: CGFloat = 80.0
        for var y = self.frame.height; y > 0; y = y - circleDiameter
        {
            let coloroptions = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.redColor()]
            let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coloroptions.count)))
            let color = coloroptions[randomNumber]
            var rect = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, y, circleDiameter, circleDiameter)
            var circle = SKShapeNode()
            circle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect).CGPath
            circle.fillColor = color
            circle.lineWidth = 0
            circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.frame.width / 2)
            circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            self.addChild(circle)
        }
```